# Sequelize recent problem with attributes: []?

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

this is is little bit weird. Sequelize query stopped working after... 1 year of functioning.

```
const where = { ... };
const attributes = ['id', 'code']; // This one making problems
const include = [...];

return SiteDao.findAll({ where, include, attributes });
```

I really didn't understand this because everything worked well, even try to logg queries and try them directly on DB, and they worked. Then I found that attributes broke it... But why? This is working for me

```
const where = { ... };
const attributes = { include: ['id', 'code'] }; // This one works for me
const include = [...];

return SiteDao.findAll({ where, include, attributes });
```

I don't really get it, because [official documentation](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/querying/) using the first version of attributes

My question is, why this happened and is it possible to somehow fix it, it's like every other api is using projection on attributes....

Answer (score 0):

I think this documentation is a bit out of date or i suspect this works for an earlier version of sequelize than the one you are using.  The official documentation explains how both options can be used. [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll)

Both

```
const attributes = ['id', 'code'];

const attributes = { include: ['id', 'code'] };
```

Should have been valid options. I suspect the ['id', 'code'] is translated in sql like column 'id' as 'code' cause there is an option to change the name of the attributes. You should try

```
 const attributes = [['id','id'], ['code','code']];
```

If you want to keep your code consistent for the clarity.